# Expanding the content by click it

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

When i click the `more`. I wanted the content should expand. I my page i have about 10 question with more option. The question content is coming through the php script.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
//fetch the data.
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $question = $data['question'];
      echo "<span class=\"spanstyle\" id=\"fullquestion\">" . substr($question, 0, 170);
      echo  "...<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"contentExpand();\">more</a></span><br>";
      }
}   
?>
```

I try to do that by javascript. `ContectExpand()` fire of when i click.

```
<script>
function contentExpand() {
    var question = <?php echo $question; ?>;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = question;
}
</script>
```

Problem is, `$question` is changing the value as it is inside the loop. It doesn't have a fixed value.

Also I want to know that I can do that only along with php without javascipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my solution you need some sort of $data['id'], which is unique for each question..  I think it cannot be done only in PHP, but you should try to use jQuery, it makes javascript much easier

```
<?php
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
  //fetch the data.
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $question = $data['question'];
        echo "<span class='spanstyle' id='shortQuestion{$data['id']}'>" . substr($question, 0, 170).
           "...<a href='#' onClick='return contentExpand({$data['id']});'>more</a></span>
  <span class='spanstyle' id='longQuestion{$data['id']}'>{$data['question']}</span>
  <br>";
        }
  }   
  ?>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function contentExpand( fullcontentId ) {
   document.getElementById('shortQuestion'+fullcontentId).style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('longQuestion'+fullcontentId).style.display = "inline";
   return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with you code. Regarding your question, the most important are:

1. The *while* loop is generating several *span* elements with the same *id*.
2. The *onClick* function should content a reference to the element you want to expand.
3. You dind't include any code constraining the size of the *span* element, so there is nothing to be expanded.

How to fix them:

### Modify the while loop

Create a *$i* variable that counts the rows and add it to the *span id*, to the *link id* and to the javascript function in this way:

```
$i = 0;
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $i++;
    $question = $data['question'];
    echo "<span class='spanstyle' id='fullquestion_" . $i. "' >";
    echo  "<a href='#' id='link_" . $i . "' onClick='contentExpand(" . $i. ");'>more</a> ";
    echo $question."</span><br>";
  }
```

### Create a javascript function that resize the span element:

You didn't tell us *how* you want to expand the content. There would be a lot of different ways to achieve it. This is just one that tries to respect your HTML markup, but surely not the best:

```
<script>
function contentExpand(id) {
    var link = document.getElementById('link_'+id);
    var span = document.getElementById('fullquestion_'+id);
    if(link.innerHTML=='more')
    {
        link.innerHTML = 'less';
        span.style.width = '100px';
    }else{
        link.innerHTML = 'more';
        span.style.width = 'auto';
    }
}
</script>
```

### Modify the css of the span element:

A block element like a *div* would suit better anyway, but maybe you have very good reasons to use a *span*.

```
span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: right;
}
```

## How to do it without javascript (just PHP):

It is certainly possible, but I guess you don't want to do it.

But if still you want to do so, generate the loop with just partial information about the related *$question* (as you do in the original code, `substr($question, 0, 170)`) but put the elements inside a form.

When the user click the `more` *span* element, submit the form to send from the client back to the server the information about the selected item.

Then, the PHP script would generate again the page but, this time, the selected item will load the full text of the *question* (`$question` instead of `substr($question, 0, 170)`).

So, you will have to make a new HTTP request call (that means to reload the page, AJAX is not an option if you don't want to use javascript).

Doing all this add a new layer of complexity and make it less efficient.
My advice is, if you don't have strong reasons to don't use javascript, use it.